# web address for document library in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

I'm using the SharePoint Query Tool to query for documents in a document library on SharePoint Online.  What Path:... should I be using.

The path to the library in Document Library Settings is:
https://Company.sharepoint.com/subsite/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx

I've tried https://Company.sharepoint.com/subsite/Shared%20Documents/*

Ultimately I need to query for all documents in that library.

Thanks!

Comment: can you post your code for the query?  The ../subsite/Share%20Documents is the right path

Comment: Please try "../subsite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('[Doc Library Name]')/items".

Comment: As it turns out, I was also filtering on FileType:pdf* which clearly conflicted with * in the Path: property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about the Connection URL, you can use any valid URL for the search API. `https://tenant.sharepoint.com` or `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/search`. Then to only hit the doc library in question you can use the `path` Managed Property. `path:https://tenant.sharepoint.com/subsite/*`.